# Add css style value via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, smarty, prestashop

I want to make a header with random images on page load with use of little jquery.
I found this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var path = '{$base_dir}img/header/',
 imgs = ['h1.jpg', 'h2.jpg', 'h3.jpg', 'h4.jpg', 'h5.jpg'],
 i = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
 $('.random').append("<img src='"+path+imgs[i]+"'>").hide().fadeIn(500);        
</script>
```

My header looks like:

```
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header_body"> 
        <a id="header_logo"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

After compile the smarty template site source code looks like here:

```
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header_body"> 
        <a id="header_logo"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://xxx/img/header/h3.jpg">
</div>
```

And its not good because i need to fill the "header_containter" with random image that should be something like that

```
<div id="header_container" style="background: url(http://xxx/img/header/h3.jpg) no-repeat center top !important;">
    <div id="header_body"> 
        <a id="header_logo"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i want to add css style property via jquery or other way? Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P2d7d/) Use `.css` in jQuery. Replace the link I put in there with your random image url.

Comment: Looks promising! I will test it and give feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your image names should be 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg .....

Then using jquery you can do something like this. Every time it set one of image as background image from 6 of image list.
*Change the image path as you need.*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var numOfImages = 6;
    var imageName = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * numOfImages )+ ".jpg";
    $('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/"+imageName+")"); 
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cF8fQ/1/

Comment: Nayana Adassuriya perfect solution! Works like a harm! +1 from me :)
Is there any way to cache this images to load faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method this way:

```
$(selector).css('property', 'value');
```

In your case, this would be:

```
$("#header_container").css('background', "url('http://xxx/img/header/h3.jpg') no-repeat center top;");
```

Edit at will, this should point you in the right direction.

Best.

Comment: Just edited it, it should be a proper answer now. Best.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Also read more http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Also recommend the other styles be applied via actual CSS styling (`no-repeat center top !important` etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can set inline css values easily with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
$("#header_container").css({
    "background": "url('your-image.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat",
    "background-size": "cover"
});
```

This also uses a css3 property [background-size:cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to make sure the image fully covers the header area. This probably won't work on older browsers.